# Command virsh blockcommit in script shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, kvm-virtualization

I'm facing a weird issue... I'm trying to create a shell script to live backup  Vms on KVM.

To perform this, I need a step with a blockcommit to merge the snapshot created with the base disk.

All works well, except the remote virsh command blockcommit. I use a several virsh command inside my script like `snapshot-create`,  `list --all`, `dumpxml`, I got an error only with the blockcommit.

Here the command use in my script and the error result:

```
ssh -n $SERVER "virsh blockcommit $VM $DISK --active --pivot"
erreur : Numeric value '-–pivot' for <bandwidth> option is malformed or out of range
```

I tried to put a numeric value before `--active` but I got another error :

```
erreur : invalid argument: could not find image '-–pivot' beneath '/mnt/07cc8e4c-92e4-39ff-875a-15e05e524684/cfc66c90-4833-466f-b969-d6c32240c10b.backup_TESTVM_hda.qcow2' in chain for '/mnt/07cc8e4c-92e4-39ff-875a-15e05e524684/cfc66c90-4833-466f-b969-d6c32240c10b.backup_i-5-298-VM_hda.qcow2'
```

It's like the option is not interpreted in the good order.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?
Command works fine directly in the KVM host.

Comment: Have you set VM and DISK? Probably one of them is empty.

Comment: yep, i set up variable before test script and use echo to confirm...anyway, i found tje solution...and it was pretty simple..
i changed the command 
'virsh blockcommit $VM $DISK --active --pivot'

to

'virsh blockcommit $VM $DISK --pivot --active. i just switched order options